# How to correctly install scanner driver for Brother MFC-L2700DW on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner

I have a all-in one printer/scanner Brother **MFC-2700DW**
I can download and even install the DEB package from the Linux drivers on the producer's page. However, when i try to scan with simple scan I am getting errors. If i run simple scan as root

```
sudo simple-scan
```

Then it is able to scan. It seems to be an issue with the driver that wrongly assumes the wrong permissions.

To make it cleaner I am trying to install the drivers on a live-usb ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f9:0331 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I run it as non-root I am getting either core dumps or "unable to connect to scanner". However, if I start it as sudo everything works

Here are the debug logs when i start non-root **simple-scan -d**

```
[+6.46s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:341: sane_get_devices () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+6.46s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:353: Device: name="brother4:bus2;dev6" vendor="Brother" model="MFC-L2700DW" type="USB scanner"
[+6.56s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1775: Saving state to /home/ubuntu/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+18.04s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1775: Saving state to /home/ubuntu/.cache/simple-scan/state
...
[+24.53s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:454: Requesting scan at 300 dpi from device 'brother4:bus2;dev6'
[+24.53s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1569: Scanner.scan ("brother4:bus2;dev6", dpi=300, scan_mode=ScanMode.COLOR, depth=8, type=ScanType.SINGLE, paper_width=0, paper_height=0, brightness=0, contrast=0, delay=10000ms)
[+24.53s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:806: Processing request
[+24.53s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:867: sane_open ("brother4:bus2;dev6") -> SANE_STATUS_IO_ERROR
[+24.53s] WARNING: scanner.vala:871: Unable to get open device: Error during device I/O
[+24.63s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1775: Saving state to /home/ubuntu/.cache/simple-scan/state


...
```

The program error seems to be :
sane_open ("brother4:bus2;dev6") -> SANE_STATUS_IO_ERROR
Unable to get open device: Error during device I/O

Comment: You're root in a live session and typically there aren't any other user. It makes sense it needs sudo to run. Other than that there's likely nothing wrong with the drivers installation.

Comment: I am not root. I am "ubuntu" which is the live-session gui user. It happens to have sudo rights but is not root. **whomai** answers **ubuntu**.  **sudo whoami** ansers **root**

Answer (score 1):

User should be in the group scanner. Control it with `id` This avoids to start scan-programms with sudo. `sudo usermod -a -G scanner USERNAME` for USERNAME choose **your** username. Logout and login again. This is only possible in a installed System not in a Live-Session

Edit: I was wrong I forgot `newgrp  scanner` then you are in the group scanner.

Comment: can you elaborate why it should not work on a live session with preserved state ? Can it be done without logout, like reloading cache or restarting sane daemon ? I did so many tries on the main system that now I consider it unreliable for this test.

Comment: Expand answer. Ping.

Comment: This has worked for me on an installed system. After I added the user to the scanner group, both XSane and Simple Scan started working with the user. Before that only root could scan.